# Docker - automount guest's fstab entries on boot

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I have set up my docker ubuntu image and run it in privileged mode.
My problem is: inside my container, I've added a CIFS share entry inside on fstab file.
If I manually run mount -a from inside my container, the volume will be mount ok... but, at startup of my container (from docker) the volume is not mapped automatically... I need to log inside my container and mount it manually.
How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: You would need to arrange to run `mount -a` as part of your container startup, using either the `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` directives in your Dockerfile.

Comment: @larsks I don't have Dockerfile. I've downloaded the image from a repository. I tried crontab, but it doesn't works.

Comment: So then write a Dockerfile that starts with the existing image, adds whatever commands and other configuration you want, and produces a new image that meets your needs.

Comment: @larsks I'm a newbie of Docker. Since now, I start the container with some port mapping and --privileged flag.... What type of dockerfiles (I mean strucuture) can I use?

Comment: What docker image are you using and how are you running it? could you share the `docker run` command you are using?

Comment: @cml.co sorry for my late answer. Basically I have downloaded the image form QNAP Container Station. I can export the entire image locally and create (maybe) the DOCKER FILE start from it... Or, maybe, can I create my image from scratch and mount the share from inside operating system (Ubuntu)... Do you have any suggestion? Thank you.